# Convert this Weigth/Score DataFrame into List of Coulmn name with sorted according to their Weigth/Score Matrix Format DataFrame in Python Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, data-science

- Convert this User-Category Score into User-Top3-Category score DataFrame with User and there 3 max Categories name in Python Pandas Dataframe

  ```
  Input DataFrame
  user_id  cat_1  cat_2   cat_3   cat_4   cat_5   cat_6
  1        0.10   0.2     0.20    0.12    0.7     0.6 
  2        0.6    0.20    0.12    0.15    0.13    0.11    
  3        0.11   0.10    0.8     0.12    0.3     0.7
  4        0.2    0.11    0.12    0.6     0.9     0.21
  5        0.9    0.8     0.5     0.1     0.0     0.11    


  Desired Output DataFrame
  user_id     top_3_categories
  1           [cat_3, cat_4, cat_1]
  2           [cat_2, cat_4, cat_3]
  3           [cat_4, cat_1, cat_2]
  4           [cat_6, cat_3, cat_2]
  5           [cat_6, cat_1, cat_2]
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) for positions by sorted values per rows with broadcasting columns names and filtering only 3 values per rows:

```
df = df.set_index('user_id')
arr = df.columns.values[np.argsort(-df.values)[:, -3:]].tolist()

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'user_id': df.index, 'top_3_categories':arr})
print (df1)
   user_id       top_3_categories
0        1  [cat_3, cat_4, cat_1]
1        2  [cat_5, cat_3, cat_6]
2        3  [cat_4, cat_1, cat_2]
3        4  [cat_1, cat_3, cat_2]
4        5  [cat_6, cat_4, cat_5]
```

Or:

```
arr = df.columns.values[np.argsort(-df.values)[:, :3]].tolist()

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'user_id': df.index, 'top_3_categories':arr})
print (df1)
   user_id       top_3_categories
0        1  [cat_5, cat_6, cat_2]
1        2  [cat_1, cat_2, cat_4]
2        3  [cat_3, cat_6, cat_5]
3        4  [cat_5, cat_4, cat_6]
4        5  [cat_1, cat_2, cat_3]
```

Comment: @Sanjeevsingh - thank you, I try understand your expected output and not understand it, is possible change it? Because some rows matched, some not.

Comment: @Sanjeevsingh - Are some values duplicated like `0.20` in first row? It should be reason for difference.

Comment: yeah, some values are duplicates in case of a large number of columns. I am computing with 4500 columns in the data frame.

Comment: @Sanjeevsingh - it should be difference, e.g. in sample data for first row are 2 correct values `[cat_3, cat_4, cat_1]` and `[cat_2, cat_4, cat_1]`, because `cat_2` and `cat_3` is `0.2`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192344/discussion-between-sanjeev-singh-and-jezrael).

Comment: Categories - Top 3 users id
Desired Output DataFrame


cat_name     top_3_user_id
cat_1        [3, 1, 5]
cat_2        [2, 4, 3]
cat_3        [1, 2, 4]
cat_4        [2, 1, 3]
cat_5        [4, 5, 2]